# Scan Multiple Documents and Trigger One Workflow

Tags: workflow

We need to scan multiple documents and have the scanner user trigger a workflow after a certain number of documents have been assembled together. We have been considering using a Document Set in SharePoint 2010. But vendors such as Kodak and KnowledgeLake do not yet support scanning directly to a Document Set. They have options for Lists, Folders, Document Libraries, etc, but no options for Document Sets.

**Use Case:**

- Scanner user scans in receipt.
- Scanning software prompts user to
  select a location for the document in
  SharePoint.
- User Selects the Expense Reports index.
- Scanning
  software prompts user to associate
  the document with an instance of a
  SharePoint workflow by selecting from
  an existing list of instances, or
  creating a new instance.
- User
  names the new instance “Expense
  Report for September 2010”
- System processes the scan.
  (the workflow does not kick off yet)
- Scanner
  user scans in another receipt.
  Scanning software prompts user to
  select a location for the document in
  SharePoint.
- User Selects Expense
  Reports.
- Scanning software
  prompts user to associate the
  document with an instance of a
  SharePoint workflow by selecting from
  an existing list of instances, or
  creating a new instance.
- User
  selects “Expense Report for September
  2010”
- System processes the
  scan.
   (the workflow does not kick
  off yet)
- Scanner user scans in an
  expense report.
- Scanning software
  prompts user to select a location for
  the document in SharePoint.
- User
  Selects Expense Reports.
- Scanning
  software prompts user to associate
  the document with an instance of a
  SharePoint workflow by selecting from
  an existing list of instances, or
  creating a new instance.
- User
  selects the “Expense Report for
  September 2010”
- System processes
  the scan.
- User Selects "Scanning
  Complete"
- System kicks off the
  workflow…

Answer (score 1):

i suggest that custom workflows take care of the batching within a workflow once kofax or knowledgelake can scan the documents in.

the scanning software couuld tag each document with a unique id which you could use to tie the common documents together..

this way, a workflow can batch them into a document set and also late arriving documents will be catered for.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

Another option could be a scan dropoff point, a doc lib that is emptied out after each scanning batch.

After the scan batch is complete, kick off a (custom) site workflow that processes each document, then empties out the lib. To make sure no other batch interferes with the current 1, mark the items with a common (batch) number like femi said. When the scan batch is done, kick off the site wf with the batch number as initiation parameter (and perhaps the final destination lib's title / id)